# How to setup K9 Mail properly for free email services offering multiple aliases for same email box?

Tags: settings, email, accounts, k9-mail

Tried Googling for a lot of results but did not find any that can show how to setup email accounts that offer using multiple email aliases to users on same email. I am talking mainly about Outlook.com and ability to send from my email account there using different aliases like joedoe@outlook.com or superjoe@outlook.com while all arriving email will arrive to main email box. I also wonder if certain filters can be set up that would establish folders for respective email aliases to keep myself organized)

I tried playing with settings, different combinations but nothing worked and brought me errors.

- I tried settings like using @outlook.com instead of @hotmail.com or
  my email address but without @outlook.com or @hotmail.com for my
  username.
- Tried m.outlook.com and snt-m.outlook.com and same with hotmail.com
- Tried enabling SSL/TLS security with default port 443 and no security

Can anyone suggest me appropriate course of action to setup K9 Mail at least for Outlook.com to be able to use email alias I have there? I think it involves setting up exchange type of account.

Thanks.

*Android 4.3*

*K9 Mail latest version*

Comment: And do you want K9 to be able to use IMAP/POP to send and receive email *as* the alias email instead of the final destination mailbox?

Comment: @StephenSchrauger I guess it's rather using multiple aliases for the same mailbox, which are handled by the server – so e.g. john@example.com and john.doe@example.com end up in the same mailbox automatically (note the *free email services **offering aliases*** in the question's title). Boris then most likely wants to answer mails adressed at john@example.com with this address, and john.doe@example.com the same way (respond with the address the mail was sent to).

Answer (score 1):

In *K-9*, when in your Inbox, hit the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key and chose *Settings→Account→Compose→Identities*. You should see a "Standard Identity" already in place. Hit <kbd>Menu</kbd> again, and chose to add a new identity. Think of "identity" as a synonym to your "alias".

I've not used this feature myself, but reports say *K-9* also automatically choses the correct alias when replying to a mail.

Comment: Not good. All it does is add my alias to "Reply To" address but still sends from main address.