# Is it possible to use multiple accounts from one email address in K9 application?

Tags: email, k9-mail

In the company I work for We would like to use one general email address, but different accounts. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible (Related [How to setup K9 Mail properly for free email services offering multiple aliases for same email box?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65051/131553))

K9 mail isn't really active in development and I would rather suggest you switch to a modern Email Client which **does this and much more**. I am talking of [FairEmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65051/131553). Don't be discouraged by "unreleased"  status. It's very much functional and actively developed. See this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/source-email-t3824168).

Specific to your query see [FAQ 9](https://github.com/M66B/open-source-email/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq9)

I am not associated with the app but would happily recommend this being a better alternative to K9 mail - it's leagues ahead of K9